# How to set 3306 port free after uninstalling MySQL?

Tags: mysql, windows, port

I just uninstalled MySQL server, restarted my laptop and reinstalled MySQL server on Windows 8.1.

When I tried to configure it, it said "Port 3306 is already in use" (or something). I know I can use another port number, but I wanted to know how to set 3306 port free and use it.

Comment: Whaddya mean 'or something'? What is the **actual message?** Don't post drivel like that here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the port should not be in use anymore.

Did you try out who uses that port? try netstat -ao. Will return you a list of opened ports plus the process id of the program that uses that. You can check which program it is in Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there must be some process binding to the port.

Have a look at this answer on a similar topic to find out which process it is:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718720/4989423)

Once you have the info in hand you can deal with the process - whether it is a remainder of the old mysql installation or something else.